# Does it span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a T/F question and I think I know the direction to go, but I am not sure.

It states: $\{[17,6,-4]^t,[2,3,3]^t,[19,9,-1]^t\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let me get this straight. It SPANS if the system is linearly DEPENDENT.
It DOES NOT SPAN if the system is linearly INdependent (if there is a unique solution, namely a zero vector).

Am I right?

Comment: Nope, you've got it backwards. They need to be linearly independent for three vectors to span all of a 3-dimensional vector space.

Comment: What if I had 3 2x1 matrices and spanning ℝ^2? Does this still apply?

Comment: Not 3 vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ are independent.

Comment: You can say that if you have a set of vectors that span $n$-dimensional space, then there must be $n$ of those vectors that are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three linearly *independent* vectors span $\Bbb R^3$. If three vectors doesn't span $\Bbb R^3$, then they are linearly *dependent*. A set of vectors is linearly dependent if one of them is a linear combination of the others. Your third vector is the sum of the first two. Therefore...

Comment: What if I had 3 2x1 matrices and spanning ℝ^2? Does this still apply?

Answer (score 0):

If the system is linearly dependent, then it does *not* span the whole space. If it is linearly independent, then it does span the space. So are the vectors
$$
v_1= \pmatrix{17 \\ 6 \\ -4}, v_2= \pmatrix{ 2 \\ 3 \\ 3}, v_3= \pmatrix{19 \\ 9 \\ -1}
$$
linearly (in)dependent?

That is, can you find (numbers) $a_1, a_2, a_3$ not all zero such that
$$
a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = 0
$$

Comment: What if I had 3 2x1 matrices and spanning ℝ^2? Does this still apply?

Comment: @Brent: Yes, if you have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then they span the whole space.